# CSS fading animation delay timing

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a slideshow effect with css3 I have three images which I need to fade into each one another.  - each transition needs to last for 3 seconds.

1st image shows for 3seconds then fades to 2nd and same to third

I'm unsure how to work out the percentage for the keyframes.

Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYmPYp

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   17% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   92% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   17% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   92% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   17% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   92% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
 @keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   17% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   92% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
 .team-img {
   position: relative;
   height: 329px;
   width: 450px;
 }
 .team-img img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 0;
   -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
   -moz-animation-duration: 9s;
   -ms-animation-duration: 9s;
 }
 .team-img img:nth-of-type(1) {
   -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
   -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
   -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 }
 .team-img img:nth-of-type(2) {
   -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
   -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
   -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 }
 .team-img img:nth-of-type(3) {
   -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
   -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
   -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 }
```

```html
<div class="team-img">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blackdogballroom.co.uk/nws/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/11/BDB-290212-Img-048.jpg">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-I2TYXJ3lDYw/UFsjvkedaXI/AAAAAAAAE-w/7EYzTeZMpsc/s1600/00Halloween+Spooks.JPG">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blog.lafraise.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Free-hug-zoneinfinite.jpg">

</div>
```

I've been racking my brain for a few hours, slowly losing the will. I've googled effortlessly.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I do not understand the problem.  Please clarify what this means:  "I have three images which I need to fade into each one another - each transition needs to last for 3 seconds."

Comment: I'm trying to create a slideshow effect with css3 I have three images which I need to fade into each one another.  - each transition needs to last for 3 seconds.

1st image shows for 3seconds then fades to 2nd and same to third

Comment: Do you mean a cross fade? If so check this out, some good examples http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to animate the first image, only the second and third. It makes a code much shorter:

```css
.team-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 329px;
  width: 450px;
}
.team-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.team-img img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fading2 ease 14s infinite;  
  animation: fading2 ease 14s infinite;
}
.team-img img:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fading3 ease 14s infinite;  
  animation: fading3 ease 14s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fading2 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  21% { opacity: 0;}
  35% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fading2 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  21% { opacity: 0;}
  35% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fading3 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  56% { opacity: 0;}
  70% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fading3 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  56% { opacity: 0;}
  70% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="team-img">
   <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blackdogballroom.co.uk/nws/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/11/BDB-290212-Img-048.jpg">
   <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-I2TYXJ3lDYw/UFsjvkedaXI/AAAAAAAAE-w/7EYzTeZMpsc/s1600/00Halloween+Spooks.JPG">
   <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blog.lafraise.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Free-hug-zoneinfinite.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define three different `@keyframes` to achieve this.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes two {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  8.3% { opacity: 0; }
  16.6% { opacity: 0; }
  24.9% { opacity: 0; }
  33.2% { opacity: 1; }
  41.5% { opacity: 1; }
  49.5% { opacity: 1; }
  58.1% { opacity: 1; }
  66.4% { opacity: 0; }
  74.7% { opacity: 0; }
  83% { opacity: 0; }
  91.3% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes two {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  8.3% { opacity: 0; }
  16.6% { opacity: 0; }
  24.9% { opacity: 0; }
  33.2% { opacity: 1; }
  41.5% { opacity: 1; }
  49.5% { opacity: 1; }
  58.1% { opacity: 1; }
  66.4% { opacity: 0; }
  74.7% { opacity: 0; }
  83% { opacity: 0; }
  91.3% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes three {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  8.3% { opacity: 0; }
  16.6% { opacity: 0; }
  24.9% { opacity: 0; }
  33.2% { opacity: 0; }
  41.5% { opacity: 0; }
  49.5% { opacity: 0; }
  58.1% { opacity: 0; }
  66.4% { opacity: 1; }
  74.7% { opacity: 1; }
  83% { opacity: 1; }
  91.3% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes three {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  8.3% { opacity: 0; }
  16.6% { opacity: 0; }
  24.9% { opacity: 0; }
  33.2% { opacity: 0; }
  41.5% { opacity: 0; }
  49.5% { opacity: 0; }
  58.1% { opacity: 0; }
  66.4% { opacity: 1; }
  74.7% { opacity: 1; }
  83% { opacity: 1; }
  91.3% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.team-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 329px;
  width: 450px;
}
.team-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.team-img img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: two 11s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
  animation: two 11s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
}
.team-img img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: three 11s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
  animation: three 11s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-img">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blackdogballroom.co.uk/nws/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/11/BDB-290212-Img-048.jpg">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-I2TYXJ3lDYw/UFsjvkedaXI/AAAAAAAAE-w/7EYzTeZMpsc/s1600/00Halloween+Spooks.JPG">
  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://blog.lafraise.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Free-hug-zoneinfinite.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The last image changes back to first without fading as it should be.

Comment: Now it's much better :) And with two animations instead of three it's shorter. It's my answer deserved a vote too?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for all those who posted. One question though, what's the calculation to work out the percentages for the keyframes?

Comment: @rapture89 - `3s delay + 1s animation + 3s delay + 1s animation + 3s delay + 1s animation = 12s`. Hence,  `100% / 12s = 8.33333%`.