# css animation different timing forward and reverse

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a simple 3 image slide show by swapping the z-index of the 3 images. I'm giving each of them 4 seconds of time before the next image swaps in.  It works fine for the first cycle, but there after the first image doesn't show up anymore.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.HPLIMG1 {
  z-index: 0;
  animation: move 4s linear 0s infinite alternate; 
  }
 @keyframes move {
  from { z-index: 100; }
  to { z-index: 400; }
}
.HPLIMG2 {
  z-index: 0;
  animation: move1 4s linear 4s infinite alternate; 
  }
 @keyframes move1 {
  from { z-index: 100; }
  to { z-index: 400; }
}
.HPLIMG3 {
  z-index: 0;
  animation: move2 4s linear 8s infinite alternate; 
  }
 @keyframes move2 {
  from { z-index: 100; }
  to { z-index: 400; }
}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<div>
<img src="1.png" class="HPLIMG1" style="position:relative"/>
<img src="2.png" class="HPLIMG2" style="position:relative; left:-200px; margin-right:-200px"/>
<img src="3.png" class="HPLIMG3" style="position:relative; left:-200px; margin-right:-200px"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to stagger the start time of each animation by 4 seconds. I've come to realize that this is likely a timing (frequency) issue because it takes 4 seconds to switch z index, but then another 4 to switch it back.  So now I'm wondering if there is a way to animate it slowly in one direction, and then quickly the other?  Is there possibly a better solution such as having one animation trigger another or using transitions (not sure if transitions can be time triggered rather than event triggered) .

I'm completely new to CSS, and I haven't been able to find an answer to this in any of the other posts.

Comment: See how to make it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066711/css-fading-animation-delay-timing/28068566#28068566

Comment: @Alexander Dayan It works beautify.  I'm just picking it apart now to try to understand how it works.